# Saving Excel Sheets and PDFs to SharePoint with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

The VBA program´s purpose is to fill the inserted information into an excel sheet, which after completion, is converted into a PDF file. The User is then asked to select a path to where it will be saved. Now I also want to save that PDF to a fixed destination of a SharePoint. Until now, I could not figure out how I´m supposed to tell VBA the path of that SharePoint. Below is the current way of saving my files. Does saving to a SharePoint work in a similar manner?

```
Sheets("Example").Select

Dim varResult As Variant
Dim ActBook As Workbook

'Select path and file name
'PDF
varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
            "PDF (*.pdf), *.pdf", Title:="Save File", _
             InitialFileName:="Example " & UserForm2.TextBoxExampleNumber.Value)
             
'Adding Key words 

ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Keywords") = UserForm2.TextBoxExampleNumbewr.Value & " " & UserForm2.TextBoxDate.Value & " " & UserForm2.TextBoxUsername.Value & " XXX" & " YYY" & " ZZZ"

'PDF EXPORT
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Filename:=varResult, Type:=xlTypePDF, OpenAfterPublish:=True, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True
```

Comment: This is the SharePoint´s URL: http://sharepoint.xxx.biz/IQ/All%20Files/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Comment: Try this in explorer \\sharepoint.xxx.biz\IQ\All Files\ and if it works you can set the path to be this or you can map a network drive if you want.

Comment: @ElioFernandes doesn´t work

Comment: What was the error  that you got? 
I have a sharepoint site https://sharecorp.xxxx.yy/teams/DOC/ and I put this \\sharecorp.xxxx.yy\teams\DOC\ and it worked. Try going step by step.

Comment: You may first need to visit sharepoint using IE in order to set the security token needed for the "WebDAV" access using windows explorer...

Comment: @ElioFernandes it says "404 not found"

Comment: another possiblity is that the sharepoint is not yet properly connected to to our comany´s system and not accessable. Maybe that´s why I´m getting that "404 not found" message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use sharepoint too - and I have macros that can upload directly to Sharepoint.
You need to establish a connection between File Explorer and Sharepoint.

1. Open Sharepoint in Internet Explorer (not Chrome)
2. Within the top menu bar, go to library and then under "Connect & Export" click on "Open with Explorer". This would open the Sharepoint file path in file explorer and will look something like:
   Network(XXX)/https://sharepoint.xxxx.com/page
3. then you can input this path as the target file path in your vba. It should upload directly to Sharepoint so long as the path is matching exactly what you have mapped.